# Legality of purchasing uncirculated bricks of USD

Tags: united-states, currency, legal, usd-us-dollar

What is the legality of "purchasing" an uncirculated brick of bills similar to one like this:

[100 NEW $2 Bills Uncirculated Consecutive 2009 Notes BEP](http://www.ebay.com/itm/231278430711)

Would it be possible (and cheaper) to simply ask a bank to give you cash this way instead?  Are banks for some reason not allowed to distribute consecutive bricks of valid US currency?

Comment: All caps, colorful font, a 20% markup over face value...... Id be really worried about potential counterfeits.

Comment: @Ben Indeed, it's a curious listing. Assuming it's legit and also assuming I'm not interested in purchasing that listing (or looking for advice on doing so) what are your thoughts on the question itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, selling bills is legal. 
In fact, there are collectors of bills that have curious serial numbers, such as 7777xxxx, 8888xxxx, etc. There are eight digits to the number, I just mean the bill starts with four sevens or eights, as an example.

Yes you can ask your bank for a pack of $2 bills. I did this years ago, they told me they needed to order $2000 or 1000 bills, but they'd do it if I took half. So I had a decade or so of annoying every toll collector or cashier I gave a $2 bill.

Comment: Thanks - I wonder why it's always $2 bills. Just the novelty of them?

Comment: Exactly. See the recent Times' article - http://www.nytimes.com/2014/04/02/nyregion/two-dollar-bill-is-oddity-but-some-love-the-tender.html?_r=0

Comment: Just curious... Do you pay sales tax on the total price, or just the premium?

Comment: That's a different question, but I believe it's taxed like any other item sold on eBay.